# Unity json giving empty or null result

Tags: unity-game-engine

These are my 2 classes

```
public class Player {
    public string playerId;
    public string playerLoc;
    public string playerNick;
}
```

---

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

public static string directory = "/SaveData/";
public static string fileName = "MyData.txt";

void Start()
{
    Player[] playerInstance = new Player[2];

    playerInstance[0] = new Player();
    playerInstance[0].playerId = "8484239823";
    playerInstance[0].playerLoc = "Powai";
    playerInstance[0].playerNick = "Random Nick";

    playerInstance[1] = new Player();
    playerInstance[1].playerId = "512343283";
    playerInstance[1].playerLoc = "User2";
    playerInstance[1].playerNick = "Rand Nick 2";

    // Convert to JSON
    string dir = Application.persistentDataPath + directory;
    string playerToJson = JsonHelper.ToJson(playerInstance);
    
    Debug.Log(playerToJson);       
}
```

I'm trying to write a JSON file and read it back, but even when I try to print it with `Debug.log` the result are empty `{}`, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the [Serializable] on top of first class. Wow.